# Find the jQuery toggle state

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

How can I find the toggle state within a function? Does the function have a built in feature which will tell me i.e. toggle=on or toggle=off

Comment: Toggle toggles things - it doesn't have an on or off state.  Easiest thing would be to declare a global variable and set it to true/false in the toggle handler.

Answer (score 2):

i guess there is no pre-defined functions but you have to use this

```
var state =  $(this).is(":hidden");
alert(state);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean check if element is visible or not? .toggle() change css "display:none;" to "display: block;". Check:

```
$('#element').attr('display') == 'none' ? state = 'on' : state = 'off';
```